# Show Category Description Prestashop

Tags: categories, prestashop

i've been googeling the all day long and couldn't find any solution for that problem. 
I want my categories to show the description i gave them.
Do i need to change any hardcode or is it configurable in the backend?

thanks a lot and best regards

Answer (score 0):

The default prestashop template displays category description on the category page by default. No extra configuration should be necessary. Are you using a custom theme? If you are, or if you have edited any of the front end templates, that may be the cause.